# Cannot run sveltekit in prod using adapter node

Tags: node.js, sveltekit

My app throws errors because of dependencies only when I run it with `node build/index.js` when using [adapter-node](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node). Works fine when using `preview`

I thought it came from mongodb but the error persists when using prisma + postgresql

Here's what happens :

on build :

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
"mock-aws-s3" is imported by "mock-aws-s3?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
"aws-sdk" is imported by "aws-sdk?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
"nock" is imported by "nock?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/glob/glob.js -> node_modules/glob/sync.js -> node_modules/glob/glob.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js -> node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js -> node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/semver/classes/comparator.js -> node_modules/semver/classes/range.js -> node_modules/semver/classes/comparator.js
  ✔ done
✓ built in 3.75s
Done in 4.41s.
```

When ran with `node build/index.js` :

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mock-aws-s3' imported from /home/gmn/work/test/build/server/chunks/5-4a6e0b61.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
```

Comment: There is now an open bug report that is likely related:

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10299

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error came from the package bcrypt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same issue
solved it by installing it as a dependency (not devDependency)

```
npm rm bcrypt && npm i bcrypt
```